# Matching criteria in multiple tables in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, criteria

I need your help on the following issue.
I can't combine criteria from different tables.
For example, I have 10 "J" personnel. I want to distribute these personnel in the second table according to the department volume which is in the first table. You can see the result I want to achieve in the "Result!" column.

| Name | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| Personnel "J" | 10 |
| Personnel "K" | 5 |

Table 1:

| Department | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| A | 70 |
| B | 50 |
| C | 30 |
| D | 120 |

Table 2:

| Department | Name | Result! |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Personnel "J" | 7 |
| B | Personnel "K" | 5 |
| C | Personnel "J" | 3 |

I need to distribute personnel quantity according to the department volume.
For example personnel "J" only works in "A" and "C" departments.
Total volume of these departments are 100. (A=%70, C=%30). Total J quantity is 10. A = 10 x 70% = 7, B = 10 x 30% = 3.
Personnel "K" only works in "B" department.
Total volume of this department is 50. (B=%100).Total K quantity is 5. so B = 5 x 100% = 5

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question is not quite clear, where is your code that you having trouble with? You should refer to the HowTo post a question topics first.

Comment: I didn't write code because I couldn't think of how to write it.  i've tried something like this: SUMIF(Table1[Department];"A";Table1[Volume])/INDEX(Table2[Department];MATCH(Table2[Staff];"Personnel J";0)*SUMIF(Table0[Staff];"Personnel J";Table0[Total]))

Comment: The thing you may do is to add a column to Table 2 called, let's say, Percentage, and put there persentage of people of certain category to be placed, eg 'Department | Name | Percentage | Result!', so rows look like this 'A | Personnel "J" | 70 | formula', ' B | Personnel "K" | 100 | formula ', etc. In this cace you will be able to use a formula of type (i'm typing values, you should reference appropriate cells) "=VLOOKUP("Personnel "K", NoNameTable.Column1, 1,0) * ([cell with percentage]/100)) for result column. The "NoNametable" is the very first table you've provided

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just solved the problem:

=SUMIF(Table1[Department];"A";Table1[Volume])/SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Table1[Volume];Table1[Department];[Department]);--([Staff]="Personnel J"))*SUMIF(Table0[Staff];"Personnel J";Table0[Total])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem:

```
=SUMIF(Table1[Department];"A";Table1[Volume])/
SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Table1[Volume];Table1[Department];[Department]);
--([Staff]="Personnel J"))*SUMIF(Table0[Staff];"Personnel J";Table0[Total])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lookup Data in Two Excel Tables

[image]

```
=LET(sn,Table0[Name],sq,Table0[Qty],ld,Table1[Department],lv,Table1[Volume],
        dd,[Department],dn,[Name],ddVal,[@Department],dnVal,[@Name],
    sqSum,SUM(FILTER(sq,sn=dnVal)),
    ddd,FILTER(dd,dn=dnVal),dvd,XLOOKUP(ddd,ld,lv,0),
    dvVal,XLOOKUP(ddVal,ddd,dvd),dvSum,SUM(dvd),
    dq,sqSum*dvVal/dvSum,
dq)
```